# How to activate the mail() function in Plesk?

Tags: php, sendmail, plesk

I want to send emails from my PHP page, but the `mail()` function isn't activated, so how to activate it. Or is there any other solution that allows me to send emails using PHP without the `mail()` function? My php version is 5.4 and my server is managed by Plesk Panel.

Comment: This is less of a programming question and more of a sys admin question. Perhaps you would be better off asking this on [sf].

Comment: Is your hosting offering the mail service in your plan?

Answer (score 0):

Aksu,

We had the same problem.
Found the answer here: https://theshosting.com/knowledgebase/287/mail-function-not-working-in-PleskYour-host-may-have-disabled-the-mail-function-Plesk-Wordpress.html

Here is the short of it:
go to
 Plesk Home >> Domain >> PHP setting >> additional configuration column >> add sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks much, it worked in my Plesk Installed server.

Comment: Plesk no longer installs sendmail by default.